# Error installing package from private repository on Dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataproc

In order to inizialize my dataproc cluster i'm trying to set up keyring authentication to a private pip repository, I followed the steps on [Setting up authentication to Python package repositories](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#keyring) - Authenticating with keyring. Since i specified a service account able to read the artifact repository i didn't setup any credential. Printing my SA on logs is the one that i expect

Unfortunately, I get the following output when trying to install a package：

WARNING: 401 Error, Credentials not correct for https://europe-west1-python.pkg.dev/repo-proj/repo/simple/my-artifact/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my_artifact (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for my_artifact

I expected the keyring to handle the authentication at this step. Any suggestions for determining the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the solution to my problem was giving this scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` during the creation of the cluster